# bamboo xcode unit test - can't find workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, bamboo

I'm trying to implement automatic ios unit tests in Bamboo. But I get the error:
`AppIOS.xcworkspace does not exist.`

Step back: I tried to run my unit tests by shellscript.

```
xcodebuild \
-workspace AppIOS.xcworkspace \
-scheme App-IOS \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3' \
test | xcpretty
```

That works fine.

So I try to "translate" this to Bamboo.

This are my configs.
[image]

Before I start my unit test I print the content of directory with ´-ls´

[image]

In the internet I can't find tutorials which are up to date. 
Is there an alternative? My destination is to get a report in bamboo.

FYI: I blur the real app name. So you don't know if I make spelling mistakes. But I really checked this twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time but now I figured it out.

I don't know if it's a general issue in Bamboo, it's the normal process or if I do some wrong operations in my tasks before.

Anyway I have explicit to set the current path with `./` at the working directory. The tests will be found and everything is fine.

Don't forget to add the `OCUnit Test Parser` to the `Final Tasks` section in your `Tasks`. Then the Bamboo will print the results in `Logs`

[image]